# Leave entered details intact after alert JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I am generating an alert from my servlet to the JSP during login like this:

My dao:

```
public boolean loginCredentialsAreValid(){
.........................
return true;
}
```

My Servlet:

```
if(lmi.loginCredentialsAreValid()){
//Go to the Home Page
}else{
request.setAttribute("valid", false);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp");
}
```

My Jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(${valid == 'false'}){
alert("Could Not Login\nInvalid Credentials");
}
<script>
```

My alert is getting generated Fine But After the Alert the Page is Reloaded without all the data I had Entered. My question is how do I validate login and after the Alert, the Credentials I had entered during login are left intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialise the form fields with the values of the parameters - so that the fields are automatically populated when you return to the form after a login failure. For example, if you have a `username` and `password` form field, then you can initialise the value of the fields:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="${param.username}" />
<input type="password" name="password" value="${param.password}" />
```

Comment: Actually this is what I finally Settled for I just thought it was tedious to set the Attributes for example if you have a form that has a hundrend values.